# Database Connection in ASP.NET Site - Should it be singleton implementation?

Tags: asp.net, database, design-patterns

I am designing a typical ASP.NET site which will connect to database to retrieve and display data. Its a three tier logical implementation with database, middle and presentation layer.

Should the class which creates a connection to the database be implemented as singleton ?

Does it mean that there will be always only one connection to the database ?

I have heard of connection pooling in ASP.NET. Isn't by making it singleton, we are ignoring this feature of ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Let me be the first to say that the Database Connection shouldn't be a Singleton.

Instead, investigate the [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) pattern. Each Unit of Work should have its own connection to the database.

Answer (score 1):

A class which creates connections might be a singleton. But actual connection object should *never* be singeton.

Comment: Hmm .. Interesting .. In that scenario, there will exist multiple connections to database. .right ?

Comment: @Madhur Sure. This is exactly what modern databases are optimized for.